# Does a mapping of icon to key description exist for IntelliJ based IDEs?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Where can one find a reference that shows the mapping of IntelliJ (JetBrains) key icons to textual name or key labels. I frequently see key icons in Tip of the Day windows that do not match any key on the keyboard I happen to be using at the time. The ESC key icon baffled me today. Is there a "describe key" tool in the IntelliJ IDEs? which shows the standard JetBrains icon for that key along with some other text, possibly some aliases?

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: Please show a screenshot of what you see there. P.S. Sounds like you are on Mac, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it is a Mac.

Comment: Well, it's easy: https://www.google.com/search?q=mac+keyboard+symbols+meaning&tbm=isch . For example: http://www.osxkeyboardshortcuts.com/keyboard-symbols.html . As you can see it's not really a JetBrains' thingy, it's Apple / Mac.